# EGit - import project (only src) from github as java project

Tags: java, eclipse, github, project

I tried recently import project, which has only src ( *.java) files. I always receive errors like

```
Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
Error connecting project Navigator, no Git repositories found
```

.gitignore looks like this:

```
/bin/
# Intellij
.idea/
*.iml
*.iws

# Eclipse
.classpath
.project
.settings/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

*.class
```

I can import project (as bare src files - can't execute it no java names support etc.) BUT when I try to convert it to java project I receive errors like that at the beginning of question

@edit1
As asked .log:

```
!SESSION 2015-12-19 22:37:01.406 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.8.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-12-19 22:37:11.004
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Jakub'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2015-12-19 22:38:31.914
!MESSAGE Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ConnectProviderOperation.execute(ConnectProviderOperation.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard$8.run(GitImportWizard.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2225)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard.importProjects(GitImportWizard.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard.access$2(GitImportWizard.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard$4.run(GitImportWizard.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Contains: Error connecting project Navigator, no Git repositories found
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.egit.core 4 0 2015-12-19 22:38:31.916
!MESSAGE Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.egit.core 4 0 2015-12-19 22:38:31.916
!MESSAGE Error connecting project Navigator, no Git repositories found
```

Comment: Van you add some logging? From the Eclipse workspace/.metainfo/.log

Comment: Looks like the url you used is not the url to the git repository to clone it. Is it a public git repository from GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab or so? Can you post the url here?

Comment: Have you successfully cloned any other git repository? In Eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried to clone the repository through git command line tool? Or an other gui ?

Comment: The url to the git repository seams not correct !

Comment: This happens when I try to import as New Project Wizard (java project). When I import it as general project everything is fine BUT I cannot build it, no java autoformat or other auto prompt fill or what u call it... 
On Github there are only src files in folder, .gitignore and README.md.

Answer (score 1):

I had a a similar problem with importing my own PHP projects in eclipse. I do not know how to fix it, however changing the project into a general eclipse project when importing instead of a java project worked for me. You can then change the general eclipse project into a java project if you want to.

Comment: It worked for me as well after changing it to a general project. Not sure what was the issue behind this.